# How do I calculate $P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, combinations, arithmetic

I posted a similar question recently but this one is different.

**The full exercise is:**

A box has 7 white balls numbered from 1 to 7, and also has 3 black balls numbered from 1 to 3, we randomly draw 2 balls at once.

$P(A) = \frac{21}{45}$ A: Drawing 2 white balls.

$P(B) = \frac{1}{3}$ B: Drawing 2 balls with odd numbers.

**The question says:**

- Calculate $P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})$

**Here is how I calculated it (but it's obviously wrong and I don't understand why):**

We use combination, and that means we have to get:

(An odd number, an even number) (Even number, even number) (black ball, black ball) (black ball, white ball), this is not in order with the calculation below btw.

$P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) = \frac{C(2,3) + C(1,7) * C(1,3) + C(1,6) * C(1,4) + C(2,4)}{C(2,10)}$

$P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) = \frac{54}{45}$ which is obviously wrong. The book found it to be $\frac{13}{15}$

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my method and why didn't it work?

Comment: @Mike That was a question I made a few hours ago, and no it's completely different.

Comment: @Mike But they are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my method and why didn't it work?

The additive rule for probability works *only when* the events are disjoint.   However, your events are *not* disjoint.

For instance: the events "(odd number, even number)" and "(black ball, black ball)" have an intersection; since black balls may be odd or even numbered.

So you are over-counting common outcomes.$\def\bar{\overline}\def\P{\operatorname{\sf P}}$

You shall need to use rules like, $\forall X\forall Y:\P(X\cup Y)+\P(X\cap Y)=\P(X)+\P(Y)$  and $\forall X\forall Y:(\bar X\cup\bar Y=\overline{\,X\cap Y}\,)$ .